How does `issubclass` usually determine that a class is a subclass of another?
How does issubclass(cls, base_cls) work?
Checking whether base_cls is in cls.__mro__ or not? Or is it something else or more complicated?
issubclass(cls, base_cls) is implemented by base_cls.__subclasscheck__(self, cls) and can have a totally different behavior than the default one. Since __subclasscheck__ is also a built-in method, I could also rephrase my question:
How does the __subclasscheck__() method work by default?

I think that's the "standard" way, but see the abc module, in particular the __subclasshook__ method, for how virtual subclassing is handled.

@chepner Thank you, vIrtual subclassing can involve overriding the __subclasscheck__() method with a metaclass on the base class implementation AFAIK. This is outside of the scope of my question and I therefore edited it accordingly.

You can find the source code in https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/73906d5c908c1e0b73c5436faeff7d93698fc074/Objects/abstract.c Look at functions object_issubclass, recursive_issubclass, abstract_issubclass.

@Barmar Thank you. I've tried to understand this code but I'm really not used to the C Python interpreter's source code so that's very obscure to me (to understand what C keyword is associated to what Python concept for instance). I'll try further though.

For cpython, most of the code that handles issubclass is found in abstract.c and typeobject.c.
The function to focus on is object_issubclass, found in abstract.c. There is a line in the object_issubclass function that handles the __subclasscheck__ functionality:
checker = _PyObject_LookupSpecial(cls, &_Py_ID(__subclasscheck__));

If base_cls.__subclasscheck__ exists then checker won't be NULL and the code will call it and then convert the returned value to True or False.
